# Set expectation in Google mock using pointer to the mock object

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I request your inputs/suggestions/help regarding setting expectation to a mock method using the pointer to the mock object.
The stack is in CPP and the application creates an object of the stack class using new operator.
In the unit test, expectations need to be set on the mock object created in the source code.
Thanks a lot in advance.

Please find the code snippet below:

```
StackBT.h
class StackBT
{
   MOCK_METHOD0(registerCallbacks, void());
   MOCK_METHOD2(...)
   MOCK_METHOD4(...)
}

ApplicationBT.h:
class ApplicationBT
{
   public:
   ApplicationBT() : mpoStackBT(new StackBT())

   void init()
   {
      mpoStackBT->registerCallbacks();
   }

   friend class TestApplicationBT;

   StackBT* mpoStackBT;
}

TestApplicationBT.h
class TestApplicationBT : public ::testing::Test
{
   protected:
      virtual void SetUp ()
      {
         ptrApplicationBT = new ApplicationBT();
      }
      void TearDown()
      {
         delete ptrApplicationBT;
      }
   public:
      TestApplicationBT ()
      {
      }

      ~TestApplicationBT ()
      {
         ptrApplicationBT = NULL;
      }

      scoped_ptr<ApplicationBT> ptrApplicationBT;
};

TEST_F(TestApplicationBT, TEST_FUNC_CALL_IN_MOCK_CREATED_INSIDE_ApplicationBT_USING_NEW)
{
   EXPECT_CALL(ptrApplicationBT->mpoStackBT, registerCallbacks()).Times(1);//Need to pass the object instead of the reference to StackBT
   ptrApplicationBT->init();
}
```

Comment: Why do you have a pointer for the mock object in 1st place?

Comment: Reason is the StackBT is created inside the ApplicationBT using new operator in source code. 
And when ApplicationBT::init() is called, stackBT::registerCallbacks(). 
Hence I need to get a reference of this StackBT created inside ApplicationBT in TestApplicationBT to be able to set expectations to the same instance of the mock object.

Comment: Anyway simple dereferencing should work to specify the mock object at the expectation. But I still don't see, why it needs to be a pointer in the `ApplicationBT` class.

Comment: I'm afraid simple dereferencing will work. I tried EXPECT_CALL( *(ptrApplicationBT->mpoStackBT), registerCallbacks()).Times(1); and below compile error was thrown: "#define EXPECT_CALL(obj, call) GMOCK_EXPECT_CALL_IMPL_(obj, call), No operator "" matches these operands"

Comment: I am using pointers to mock objects myself and I can confirm that dereferencing works. This is not a general problem , just something in  your code